# How to select datepicker in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Hi how can i select datepicker from my image

i want to select 27th march 2016
 [image]
the Code for the datepicker is :

```
<div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_6" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft require-submit author…dijitDateTextBoxError dijitValidationTextBoxError dijitError" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" aria-haspopup="true" role="combobox" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_6" popupactive="true" aria-owns="dijit_form_DateTextBox_6_popup" aria-expanded="false">

    <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode">

    <span class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner">
        ::before
    </span>

</div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">

    <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="Χ "></input>

</div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">

    <input id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_6" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" role="textbox" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" placeholder="Start Date" value="" aria-required="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="true"></input>

            <input type="hidden" value=""></input>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the value to the input box with this xpath

```
//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner']
```

And just send the date in sendKeys

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner']")).sendKeys("3/27/2016");
```

Comment: I was getting an error as 'org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible'